# How to avoid losing the input focus on an HTML element inside a WebView?

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I'm currently trying to build a touch keyboard to be used with an UWP app. One of the solutions I came up with was to use a brokered component to call SendKeys funcitons with buttons (IsTabStop being set to false and ClickMode to Press to prevent any loss of focus from the input controls). So far, everything works (tested it on TextBoxes without any trouble).

The problem: I'm encountering some issues using the WebView control : when I click a button, the WebView keeps the focus, as expected; however, the DOM elements (such as HTML's `<input>` markup) lose the input focus (while still being visually selected).

I found a way to solve this by resetting the focus on the webview; but that uncovered another issue. Let's say the input element is set to select all of it's content (the string) whenever it is focused. Then, each time I click one of my buttons, the content is selected and replaced by the new letter I sent to the WebView.

So, my question is, is there any way to avoid losing the focus of the DOM object when clicking on a XAML button?

NB : I do know about the InputPane, but I can't use it for this app (due to some restrictions on the client side). Also, let me know if something is unclear, and I'll edit asap.

NB2 : I have absolutely no access to the source code of the pages that will be displayed by the WebView, nor can I rely on the presence of a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

The Anniversary Update introduced a new property [FrameworkElement.AllowFocusOnInteraction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.allowfocusoninteraction) for this scenario. Set it to false on your Button and the Button won't take the focus when it is clicked. The focus will stay on the WebView and the selection shouldn't get cleared (if not there's something else going on as well).

Prior to this there wasn't a good solution. The least bad I've seen was to call WebView.Focus() in the Button.Click handler to return the focus, then wait for the focus events to complete before proceeding in the Click hander.

If you need to target earlier systems than the Anniversary Update then you'll need to set AllowFocusOnInteraction from code after checking that it exists with ApiInformation.IsPropertyPresent . You can't do this directly in Xaml, but you can wrap the check in an attached property which can be called from Xaml. See my blog entry [ComboBox on a Flyout attached to an AppBarButton loses mouse input on 1607](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2016/09/14/combobox-from-an-appbarbutton-loses-mouse-input-on-1607/) for sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This property behaviour seems to be very close to IsTabStop (at least, I do get the same results with both).
As for the Focus() call in the Button.Click handler, that's pretty much what I did so far, but it leads to some issues depending on how the input elements are handled by the webpage.
I tried your solution, but unfortunately the focus on the WebView itself doesn't seem to be the issue. It looks like there's a click handler somewhere that make the control lose the input focus, even when the focus is kept on the WebView (not sure how it is actually handled though).

Comment: @Dragosh Are u able to solve it? I am also facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, if I recall correctly I gave up on that option entirely (that was some time ago though so I don't remember what I did instead)